# Three.js project: blank screen, no errors

Tags: three.js

I saw these [animated clouds](https://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/webgl/clouds/) created using three.js (check [here](https://github.com/WindowsVistaisCool/clouds/tree/main) for source code). This was created in 2011 and many of the methods used here, that is being imported from the `three.min.js` file, have been deprecated since. I'm trying to adjust the source code so that it works with the latest version of three.js, installed with npm. The original code used this script tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js"></script>` in index.html to import three.js. I replaced it with `<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>` in my index.html, and then wrote a main.js, with the same old code but updated the deprecated methods with appropriate updated ones. Here's my main.js:

```
// edit
import * as THREE from "three";

var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh, geometry, material;

var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;
var start_time = Date.now();

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();

function init() {
  container = document.getElementById("scene1");
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  // Bg gradient

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 32;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "#1e4877");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "#4584b4");

  context.fillStyle = gradient;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  container.style.background = "url(" + canvas.toDataURL("image/png") + ")";
  container.style.backgroundSize = "32px 100%";

  //

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    30,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    3000
  );
  camera.position.z = 6000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // edit
  // geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  // edit
  // var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
  // ...
  // )
  var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    "assets/cloud.png",
    animate,
    undefined,
    function (err) {
      console.error("An error happened.");
    }
  );
  texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;

  var fog = new THREE.Fog(0x4584b4, -100, 3000);

  material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      map: { type: "t", value: texture },
      fogColor: { type: "c", value: fog.color },
      fogNear: { type: "f", value: fog.near },
      fogFar: { type: "f", value: fog.far },
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vs").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fs").textContent,
    depthWrite: false,
    depthTest: false,
    transparent: true,
  });

  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(64, 64));

  for (var i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
    plane.position.x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
    plane.position.y = -Math.random() * Math.random() * 200 - 15;
    plane.position.z = i;
    plane.rotation.z = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    plane.scale.x = plane.scale.y = Math.random() * Math.random() * 1.5 + 0.5;

    // edit
    // THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(geometry, plane);
    geometry.copy(plane.geometry);
  }

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.z = -8000;
  scene.add(mesh);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) * 0.25;
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) * 0.15;
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  var position = ((Date.now() - start_time) * 0.03) % 8000;

  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.01;
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.01;
  camera.position.z = -position + 8000;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

There's only a blank black screen when I start the server. There are no errors either in VSCode or my browser's developer console, which is why I'm completely stuck and don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this code:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as BufferGeometryUtils from 'three/addons/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js';


var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh, geometry, material;

var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;
var start_time = Date.now();

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();

function init() {

  // Bg gradient

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 32;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "#1e4877");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "#4584b4");

  context.fillStyle = gradient;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  const backgroundTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture( canvas );
  backgroundTexture.needsUpdate = true;

  //

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    30,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    3000
  );
  camera.position.z = 6000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = backgroundTexture;

  var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WindowsVistaisCool/clouds/main/cloud10.png",
    animate
  );

  var fog = new THREE.Fog(0x4584b4, -100, 3000);

  material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      map: {
        value: texture
      },
      fogColor: {
        value: fog.color
      },
      fogNear: {
        value: fog.near
      },
      fogFar: {
        value: fog.far
      },
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vs").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fs").textContent,
    depthWrite: false,
    depthTest: false,
    transparent: true,
  });


  var geometries = [];
  var dummy = new THREE.Object3D();

  for (var i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {

    dummy.position.x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
    dummy.position.y = -Math.random() * Math.random() * 200 - 15;
    dummy.position.z = i;
    dummy.rotation.z = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    dummy.scale.x = dummy.scale.y = Math.random() * Math.random() * 1.5 + 0.5;
    
    dummy.updateMatrix();
    
    const geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(64, 64);
    geo.applyMatrix4( dummy.matrix )
    
    geometries.push(geo);
  }

  var geometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeGeometries(geometries);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.z = -8000;
  scene.add(mesh);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) * 0.25;
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) * 0.15;
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  var position = ((Date.now() - start_time) * 0.03) % 8000;

  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.01;
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.01;
  camera.position.z = -position + 8000;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/zak26c0o/